# How to count how many times that each pair of item has same order id in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to count that how many times that each pair of SKU have been ordered together(have same orderid)
I have an **order** table of customers that has 2 column **ORDERID** and **SKUID**
for an example

```
ORDERID SKUID  
1       1  
1       2  
1       3  
2       1  
2       2  
2       4  
3       1  
3       4
```

i want a result table as

```
SKU1 SKU2  COUNT  
1    2     2  
1    3     1  
1    4     2  
2    3     1  
2    4     1  
3    4     0
```

thank you

Comment: Order 1 has three SKUs, do you want to return a column for each match?

Comment: How you are defining a *pair* here?

Comment: How many sku's are we talking about?

Comment: i have almost 400 SKUs and i want to return every pair of them. my objective is i want to detect that how many time that each pair of SKU has been ordered together. such as i have SKU A B and C,my pair should be AB, AC, BC. sorry for my poor English but i need help. thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a self-join and aggregation:

```
select o1.sku, o2.sku, count(distinct o1.orderid) as numorders
from orders o1 join
     orders o2
     on o1.orderid = o2.orderid and o1.sku < o2.sku;
```

If you know that the skus are unique in each order, then you can use `count(*)` instead of `count(distinct)`.